# C# XML GetElementsByTagName

Tags: c#, xml

I have this XML:

```
 ..<MessageContent>
   <OTA_HotelResNotifRQ TimeStamp="2017-08-03T13:24:06+01:00" Version="4" ResStatus="Book">
   <HotelReservations>..
```

I have this C# code

```
doc.LoadXml(xmlresas);
            XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
            mgr.AddNamespace("df", "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05");
            XmlNodeList ReservationsListList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("<OTA_HotelResNotifRQ>");// ("HotelReservations");
```

When my code reaches

```
GetElementsByTagName("<OTA_HotelResNotifRQ>")
```

I am getting error.

I want to get all the XML nodes from node OTA_HotelResNotifRQ... and below.

What is wrong with it?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try reading the error?

Comment: Tag names do not include `<>`.

Comment: *I am getting error* - only you are able to see error, not us, unless you post it.

Comment: @SLaks surprising OP did the right thing earlier `//("HotelReservations")` and commented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
GetElementsByTagName("<OTA_HotelResNotifRQ>")
```

Should be

```
GetElementsByTagName("OTA_HotelResNotifRQ")
```

I think